# Python one liner to split string such as "192.168.0.0/24" and "8.8.8.8"?

Tags: python

In Perl or Javascript, it's a one-liner:

`my($net,  $bits) = split('/', $data, 2);`

or

`let [net, bits] = data.split('/');`

Is there a one-liner in Python? As far as I can tell, it takes several lines. For example:

```
res = data.split('/')
ip, bits = res[0], None
if len(res) == 2:
    bits = res[1]
```

or, better,

```
res = data.split('/')
ip, bits = res if len(res) == 2 else res[0], None
```

Comment: what output are you expecting to get?

Comment: I want to separate the ip from the bits, for further processing.

Comment: To work with ipaddresses use `ipaddress`: `network = ipaddress.IPv4Network("192.168.0.0/24")`

Comment: I used the networking only as an example.

Comment: @timkay Is this really a common need in other application domains? They might also have their own parsers that do the job.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`partition()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) for this if you don't mind the *slight* ugliness of an unused variable:

```
net, _, bits = "8.8.8.8".partition('/')
net, bits
# ('8.8.8.8', '')

net, _, bits = "192.168.0.0/24".partition('/')
net, bits
# ('192.168.0.0', '24')
```

Comment: Perfect! I didn't know about partition. In short, partition does what split should do.

Comment: It's weird that partition() returns the separator.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `list` unpacking when `/` is in the IP address:

```
ip, bits = data.split('/') if '/' in data else data, None
```

The ternary operator accounts for when you don't have bits information, in which case `bits = None`.

Comment: This one scans the data twice, and it's quite less readable.

Comment: @timkay, what do you mean it scans the data twice? If there's no "/", the IP address stored as is. Otherwise, it is split on "/".

Comment: The "in" operation has to scan all of data. Then the "split" operation has to scan data again.

Comment: [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization). Do whatever you feel is most natural and readable, and optimize it if it becomes a performance bottleneck. @timkay

Comment: BTW, I agree with you about the readability, but that's personal opinion.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach would be:

```
ip, *bits = data.split('/')
```

his avoid the *not enough values to unpack* problem. Just remember that `bits`, if exists, will be inside a list.

Comment: I'd award this approach 1/2 credit. Worth thinking about. Thanks.